# Integration $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(ax)}{x^2}e^{-zx}\text dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I need help solving,

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(ax)}{x^2}e^{-zx}\text dx$$

My attempt resulted in

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(ax)}{x^2}e^{-zx}\text dx = \frac{a}{2}\arctan\left(\frac{a}{z}\right) + z \ln(z^2 + a^2)$$

I doubt this is correct because when I apply it to my research of computing charge distributions I get wrong results. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that the integral exists? Near $x=0$, the integrand function behaves like $1/x$.

Comment: It looks quite similar to a laplace transform.

Comment: Perhaps useful: $\frac{\partial^{2} I}{\partial a^{2}}+\frac{\partial^{2} I}{\partial z^{2}}=0$

Comment: This question is very interesting: It yields an example where the naive change of differentiation and integration fails (Due to the non convergence of the original integral) even if one gets something by this method which looks "nice" at the first glance. 
There is definitely some regularization procedure needed, but maybe @newbie  should tell us what exactly he wants until one can proceed effectively

Answer (score 0):

You can view this integral as the Mellin transform of $\sin(a x)\exp(-z x)$ at a certain value of $s$. Using [Ramanujan's master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan's_master_theorem) as a method we have the following:
Write the series expansion of the 
$$
\sin(a x)\exp(-z x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \phi(k) \frac{(-x)^k}{k!}
$$
where 
$$
\phi(k)=\frac{i(-1)^k}{2}\left((-ia-z)^k-(ia-z)^k\right)
$$
so the Mellin transform is given by
$$
\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}\sin(a x)\exp(-zx)\;dx = \Gamma(s)\phi(-s)
$$
if we take $s=1$ then we have 
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(a x)\exp(-zx)}{x^2}\;dx = \phi(-1) = \frac{a}{a^2+z^2}
$$
the potential problem with this is that we assumed $\phi(k)$ could be extended to take negative values.